# How to get the next date which is a fraction year away from the given date?

Tags: python, date, datetime, fractions, date-manipulation

I have a datetime object called `dt` and I want to get the next date which 0.93 years away from it. I was trying `relativedelta` but it seems that the function cannot take fractional years.

```
dt = datetime.datetime(2012, 4, 30)
dt + relativedelta(years = 0.93)

>> ValueError: Non-integer years and months are ambiguous and not currently supported.
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: 0.93 = 93 years?

Comment: No, by 0.93 it means 93/100 of a full year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try multiplying the float no by the number of days in a year. This will give you 0.93 * 365 days after the current date.

```
dt = datetime.datetime.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=int(365*.93))
```

**OUTPUT:-**

```
2020-05-09 08:40:28.507170
```

**NOTE:-**

In the above process we are converting into int, because the date is needed. If some more precise time duration (i.e Hours, Minutes etc) is needed, then this process may not be the best.

Answer (score 3):

`relativedelta` doesn't support fractions. Easiest way to do this would be to convert the fraction to seconds and use that. e.g,

```
YEAR_SECONDS = 60 * 60 * 24 * 365
dt + relativedelta(seconds = int(0.93 * YEAR_SECONDS))
```